# Amazon SES, enviar emails não verificados

Tags: email, envio-de-email, amazon-aws, ses

Tenho o dominio verificado na amazon SES, mas gostaria de enviar emails de notificações para emails que não são verificados.

É necessário a verificação de todos os emails ou existe alguma configuração que me isente de realizar a verificação ?

Answer (score 2):

Aparentemente você está dentro da sandbox do SES, portanto, só conseguirá enviar emails para emails/domínios verificados.

Para enviar emails para qualquer email sem verificação, você precisa sair da sandbox: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/request-production-access.html

Geralmente, basta abrir um chamado no suporte de acordo com o tutorial acima.

Answer (score 0):

Com um domínio verificado você pode disparar emails com todas as contas do domínio em questão. Ex: x@email.com, yy@email.com. considerando que email.com seja seu domínio.

O parâmetro *from* na chama da API ou SMTP precisa ser de uma conta desse domínio (x@email.com) e o parâmetro *to* pode ser para qualquer conta se email no mundo (eu@gmail.com).

Vale lembrar que no SES seu usuário de login é a *secret key*.

Esperto ter ajudado.

Comment: No parâmetro _FROM_, utilizo de um email verificado e com o domínio verificado. Meu problema é no _TO_, aonde não aceita um email qualquer.

**(554, 'Message rejected: Email address is not verified. The following identities failed the check in region US-WEST-2: email@dominio.com.br')**

**email@dominio.com.br:** não verificado.

Comment: Confirma se seu email verificado foi na região US-West-2

Comment: O domínio está confirmado **US West Oregon** (email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com) e confirmei e testei na região **US East N.Virginia** (email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com), ocorreu o mesmo erro!